# Terraform: errors with aws_appautoscaling_target and aws_appautoscaling_policy due to IAM DynamoDBAutoscaleRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, autoscaling, terraform

**Short question:**

Why aws_appautoscaling_policy and aws_appautoscaling_target don't see recently created DynamoDBAutoscaleRole (maybe due to IAM DynamoDBAutoscaleRole eventual consistency)?

Terraform version: v0.10.7

**Long description and question:**

Terraform configuration has the following resources (creation order as described here):  DynamoDBAutoscaleRole, 
DynamoDB table, read and write auto scaling resources for table
aws_appautoscaling_policy and aws_appautoscaling_target.

Sometimes this script runs fine (with `terraform apply`), but in most cases `aws_appautoscaling_target` and `aws_appautoscaling_policy` are failed with different errors like the following:

> "aws_appautoscaling_policy.Read: Failed to create scaling policy:
>   Error putting scaling policy: FailedResourceAccessException: Unable to
>   retrieve capacity for resource: table/Preferences, scalable dimension:
>   dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits. Reason: The security token included
>   in the request is invalid. status code: 400"
>
> "aws_appautoscaling_target.Read: Error creating application
>   autoscaling target: ValidationException: Validation failed for
>   resource: table/Preferences, scalable dimension:
>   dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits. Reason: The security token included
>   in the request is invalid. status code: 400"

If I re-run `terraform apply`, sometimes multiple times, it works. `terraform plan` always runs successfully.

If I run creation of only DynamoDBAutoscaleRole (in a separate .tf file),
and after several minutes run creation of table, aws_appautoscaling_policy and aws_appautoscaling_target, this configuration always run successfully.

So I guess that **problem is in aws_appautoscaling_policy and aws_appautoscaling_target don't see recently created role** maybe due to IAM DynamoDBAutoscaleRole eventual consistency. Is the assumption true? Does exist any workaround to wait until role will be definitely seen by aws_appautoscaling_policy and aws_appautoscaling_target?

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "Read" {
  max_capacity       = 100
  min_capacity       = 5
  resource_id        = "table/Preferences"
  role_arn           = "arn:aws:iam::XXX:role/service-role/DynamoDBAutoscaleRole" 
  scalable_dimension = "dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits"
  service_namespace  = "dynamodb" 
  depends_on = [ "aws_dynamodb_table.Preferences-table", "aws_iam_role.DynamoDBAutoscale", "aws_iam_role_policy.DynamoDBAutoscale" ]
}
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "Read" {
  name = "${aws_appautoscaling_target.Read.id}"
  service_namespace = "dynamodb"
  policy_type = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id = "table/Preferences"
  scalable_dimension = "dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits"

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization"
    }
    scale_in_cooldown = 60
    scale_out_cooldown = 60
    target_value = 70
  }
  depends_on = ["aws_appautoscaling_target.Read"]
}
```

Comment: did you add the role resource `DynamoDBAutoscaleRole ` in list of `depends_on` as well?

Comment: sure, I added. resources are created in the following order (setup with `depends_on`): DynamoDBAutoscaleRole `aws_iam_role` with policy, DynamoDB table `aws_dynamodb_table`, `aws_appautoscaling_target`, `aws_appautoscaling_policy`. so in my terraform config resources are created one by one.

Comment: The order is set by terraform, not by the resource codes sequence you wrote one by one. So you have to add the depends_on in some cases.

Comment: @BMW, maybe you don't properly understand my comment. thanks, I know that. I added `depends_on` for the following resources: 
* for table (to be executed after iam policy) 
* for aws_appautoscaling_target (to be executed after table)
* for aws_appautoscaling_policy (to be executed after aws_appautoscaling_target)